# Как очистить IEnumerable

Tags: c#

**Здравствуйте!**

Подскажите как правильно очистить всю занятую память в **IEnumerable**

Собираю файлы с директории в другую папку, вначале проходит долго, после 2 запуска файлы быстро появляются собранные из памяти.

Код:

```
 public static void Viscan(string ss, string[] Format, string z)
{
    long Limit = 100000000;
    long LowLimit = 0;
    IEnumerable<string> findFiles = Directory.GetFiles(ss, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    if (Directory.Exists(z))
        foreach (string fileName in findFiles)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
            if (Array.IndexOf(Format, ext) < 0) continue;
            try
            {
                var fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
                if (LowLimit + fileSize > Limit) continue;
                File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(z, Path.GetFileName(fileName)), true);
                LowLimit += fileSize;
            }
            catch { }
        }
}
```

Comment: "файлы быстро появляются собранные из памяти" - это Вы сами так решили? И что это за ужасный `try/catch` внутри цикла?

Comment: @igor,ну я точно не знаю, сам выдумал =) Ну а по сути они же хранятся где? ( это же как-то влияет на производительность) ? А вообще что посоветуете?

Comment: Посоветовать - по какому вопросу? А во второй раз файлы, скорее всего, находятся в дисковом кэше.

Comment: @Igor, Да спасибо за наблюдение на счет `try/catch` исправлю).

Comment: `null` присвойте да и все, что вы еще хотите там очищать то? зы: поиск файлов внутрь  проверки `Directory.Exists` уберите

Comment: @teran, Я просто думал что это как-то влияет на производительность) поэтому хотел узнать нужно ли отчищать или нет, теперь буду знать) А проверка директории - Я же её не внутри цикла пихаю, почему там не желательно делать?

Comment: дак в случае если директории `z` не существует, то вы напрасно ищите файлы

Comment: зачем искать все файлы, если потом все равно проверяешь расширения? Кроме того нет смысла сохранять результат _Directory.GetFiles_ в _IEnumerable<string>_, потому что эта функция точно возвращает массив.

Answer (score 6):

```
IEnumerable<string> findFiles = Directory.GetFiles(ss, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Здесь вы определяете переменную ссылочного типа `IEnumerable<string>` с именем `findFiles`, которая в результате присваивания ссылается на объект в куче, являющийся массивом строковых переменных. Данные хранятся в управляемой куче. Переменная объявлена внутри метода, следовательно, после того, как метод отработает, ссылки на объект в управляемой куче уже не будет. Поэтому после того, как `CLR` сама в нужный момент вызовет *Garbage Collector* (сборщик мусора), памать, выделенная под вашу переменную сама освободится.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете ввиду что первые **два** запуска файлы медленно копируются, а потом быстро? Если так, то тут имеет место быть работа менеджера памяти Windows, который просто держит часто используемые файлы отображенными в память, и следовательно фактически доступ к ним мгновенный.

А по поводу очистки памяти занятой перечислимым типом, короткий ответ - прямым способом никак, т.к. всем этим занимается GC (garbage collector). Конечно можно им и руками порулить вызывая [GC.Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), но зачем? Дело то не в этом.